# Debugging - Self closing tag?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I've spent quite some time trying to find where the missing closing tag is and I'm losing my mind or have gone cross-eyed. All throughout the component I'm getting bugs that say 'Expression Expected' or 'Declaration or statement expected'

I know that I need to close the tags with a '/>/ at the end but I can't find where exactly could be causing the problem.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import logo from "../icons/logo.svg";
import CSS from "../styles/Navigation.css";
import hamburger from "../icons/icon-hamburger.svg";
import { MobileMenu} from "../components/MobileMenu"


function navigation() {
  
  return (
    <div className="navigation">
        <img className="logo" src={logo} alt="coffee-roasters-logo" />

      <button className="hamburger">
        <img src={hamburger} />
        </button>

      <div className="navigation-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">Create Your Plan</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </>
    </div>
  
  )
}

export default navigation;
```

Comment: `</>` goes with what?

Answer (score 2):

second last tag change `</>` to `</div>` to close one of the earlier divs

```
function navigation() {
  return (
    <div className="navigation">
      <img className="logo" src={logo} alt="coffee-roasters-logo" />

      <button className="hamburger">
        <img src={hamburger} />
      </button>

      <div className="navigation-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">Create Your Plan</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```